# Invariance under transition of integral

Tags: calculus

I am reading a calculus book, and in section on invariance under transition of integral I get the following passage I don't quite understand:

Suppose we have a function $s(x)$. Then we introduce another function $t(x)$, such that $t(x)=s(x)+c$, i.e. $t(x)$ is $s(x)$ shifted to the left by some arbitrary $c$.

Now the textbook says that ordinate sets of these two functions are related by the equation $t(x)=s(x-c)$. And if $s(x)$ is defined on $[a,b]$, then $t(x)$ is defined on $[a+c,b+c]$.

I can understand that if $s(x)$ is defined on $[a,b]$, then $t(x)$ is defined on $[a+c,b+c]$, what I don't understand is that why do we have $t(x)=s(x-c)$ if $t(x)=s(x)+c$?

I know this is a quite stupid question, but I can't figure this out on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not a stupid question: you’ve been victimized by two bad typos. The function $t(x)$ is supposed to be $t(x)=s(x+c)$, not $s(x)+c$; with that definition it’s no problem to check that $s(x)=t(x-c)$ (note the interchanging of the $s$ and $t$ compared to the book). Note that replacing $s(x)$ with $s(x)+c$ would actually translate the graph **up** be $c$ (so down if $c<0$), not to the left.

Comment: So if $t(x)=s(x+c)$, then how is it possible that $t(x)=s(x-c)$?

Comment: @Fazzolini: I missed the second typo: it should be $s(x)=t(x-c)$, with the two functions interchanged. (I knew what was supposed to happen and didn’t read carefully enough.)

Comment: And then, based on this, there is the following property of integral $\int_{a}^{b}s(x)dx=\int_{a+c}^{b+c}s(x-c)dx$ for every real $c$. I just don't understand this sign flipping $(x+c)$ in the definition of $t(x)$ and then $(x-c)$ in the integral property.

Comment: @Fazzolini: When $x=a+c$, $x-c=(a+c)-c=a$, and when $x=b+c$, $x-c=(b+c)-c=b$, so as $x$ runs from $a+c$ to $b+c$, $x-c$ runs from $a$ to $b$. If you let $u=x-c$, then $du=dx$, so $$\int_{a+c}^{b+c}s(x-c)dx=\int_a^ns(u)du\;,$$ and renaming the variable from $u$ to $x$ gives you the equality that you want.